# Proper Way to use Admob in Phonegap app for iOS

Tags: ios, xcode, cordova, admob

I have built an iOS app with Phonegap (Cordova 1.8.1),and now I'm trying  to add admob ads to my app.As you know that AdMob is now not allowing to chose "smartphone web", so can I just simply implementing JavaScript code in the index.html or do I need to using Admob iOS SDK?(OR JUST USING Google AdSense??)

note:

`We are simplifying our suite of products by transitioning AdMob mobile web publishers to Google AdSense. Starting May 1, 2012 support for mobile web sites on AdMob will be discontinued and you must have a Google AdSense account to monetize mobile web sites. More information is available here.`

Answer (score 1):

I believe that according to their terms of service you'll have to integrate the iOS SDK since you're still releasing a native application.

It's pretty easy to integrate an AdMob ad using the iOS SDK. In `(void)webViewDidFinishLoad:(UIWebView *)theWebView`, you can add a GADBannerView and follow the integration instructions outlined [here](https://developers.google.com/mobile-ads-sdk/docs/ios/fundamentals).

An important caveat to remember is that you'll have to decrease the size of the `UIWebView` to make room for the advertisement. Make sure the `MainViewController` is your RootViewController.

Comment: OK.I'll give it a try.and maybe I will write a blog post about it.Thanks anyway..